# Error in Modular Arithmetic calculation in Python

Tags: python, csv, newline

I have the following code in which there is a mysterious error for one particular combination of entries:

It *appears" to work fine for everything else but for the inputs: "Friday" and "1000", it throws up a variable error.

**Full Code listing:**
https://repl.it/Jd6a/0

**Code**

```
#Use of Modulo Arithmetic

def main():
  DAY="Monday"
  print("Here's a little modulo magic for ya...")
  dayofweek=input("Enter day of week (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc:")
  numberofdays=input("Enter number of days from that day of the week you would like to calculate:")

  if dayofweek=="Monday":
    dow=1 
  elif dayofweek=="Tuesday":
    dow=2 
  elif dayofweek=="Wednesday":
    dow=3 
  elif dayofweek=="Thursday":
    dow=4 
  elif dayofweek=="Friday":
    dow=5 
  elif dayofweek=="Saturday":
    dow=6 
  elif dayofweek=="Sunday":
    dow=7 

  modanswer=int(numberofdays)%7
  answer=modanswer+dow

  if answer==1:
    finalanswer="Monday"
  elif answer==2:
    finalanswer="Tuesday"
  elif answer==3:
    finalanswer="Wednesday"
  elif answer==4:
    finalanswer="Thursday"
  elif answer==5:
    finalanswer="Friday"
  elif answer==6:
    finalanswer="Saturday"
  elif answer==7:
    finalanswer="Sunday"

  print(numberofdays,"days from -",dayofweek,"-will be-",finalanswer)

main()
```

**Testing (Correct) and Error Shown below**

```
Here's a little modulo magic for ya...
Enter day of week (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc: Monday
Enter number of days from that day of the week you would like to calculate: 1000000
1000000 days from - Monday -will be- Tuesday
   main()
Here's a little modulo magic for ya...
Enter day of week (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc: Friday
Enter number of days from that day of the week you would like to calculate: 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 42, in main
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'finalanswer' referenced before assignment
```

**What I'm looking for:**

I'd be interested in a) a solution with explanation to the problem b) More elegant ways, with validation, to solve the problem (using more simple constructs perhaps)

Answer (score 4):

```
 modanswer=int(numberofdays)%7
 answer=modanswer+dow
```

`modanwer` is between 0 and 6 (inclusive), `dow` is between 1 and 7 (inclusive), so `answer` is between 0 and 13 (inclusive). You should apply the modulo operation after the addition. This might work:

```
answer = (int(numberofdays) + dow - 1) % 7 +1
```

The `-1` and `+1` are needed because your `answer` is between 1 and 7 but modulo returns a number between 0 and 6.

You could simply use a list, 0-index `day_number` and modulo:

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

day_number = days.index('Friday') # 4
offset = 1000
print(days[(day_number + offset) % 7])
# Thursday
```

Comment: Thank you! Applying the modulo operation after addition causes an error though: answer=modanswer+dow
  modanswer=int(numberofdays)%7      error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'modanswer' referenced before assignment

Comment: @MissComputing see update. You cannot use a variable which is defined one line later in Python.

Comment: Will look. Will not this simply work:   modanswer=0
  answer=modanswer+dow
  modanswer=int(numberofdays)%7
  print(answer)        ..it seems to! (as suggested below by Compoot)

Comment: @MissComputing I don't think it makes sense. `answer` is just `dow` and you don't use it in `modanswer`.

Comment: Got it! Works. Thanks. As the actual problem was pointed out by Compoot I think I'll accept answer (and it was done first). I'd like to thank you though and also upvote all your helpful comments!

Comment: @MissComputing No problem. Here's a working version of your code : https://repl.it/Jd7P/3